# Need GWT EditTextCell with different value in view mode and edit mode

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gwt, dom-events

I have a EditTextCell field in a GWT application. Let's say the string in it is:

> Hello stack overflow world

If the field value is more than certain (say 10) chars, I want to strip the text in the view, like:

> Hello stac...

but upon editing, it should show full content in the text box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this paticular cell, but my 1st thought is to overload the cell, and override the render() method:

```
@Override
public render(Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb){
if (isEditing)
   super.render(context, value, sb);
else
   super.render(context, substring, sb);
}
```

Comment: I have done exactly that but you don't need an isEditing() check - render(...) isn't called when editing.

Answer (score 1):

From [EditTextCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/EditTextCell.html) documentation, use the alternate constructor:

> EditTextCell(SafeHtmlRenderer renderer)
>  
>             Construct a new EditTextCell that will use a given SafeHtmlRenderer to render the value when not in edit mode.

When you create your [renderer](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/text/shared/SafeHtmlRenderer.html), you provide two render methods to complete the interface.  These methods should return the ellipsis form you've described.